# Android permissions, Works on API 23 but stopped working on API 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

This is what I'm using for request permission to make it work on API 23, but this made a problem that code do not want to send information though API 21.

```
private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "contacts & location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                            showDialogOK("Contacts and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

If I remove this permissions, API 21 works perfectly again.

```
public void sendGetRequest(View v) 
{ 
    int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
    if (version >= 23)
    { 
        if(checkAndRequestPermissions())  
        { //EXECUTE JSON 
            new GetClass(this).execute(); 
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        new GetClass(this).execute();
    }
}
```

Stack Trace when open with API 21:

```
05-02 15:02:41.830 12952-13251/com.sandro.openalprsample E/Volley: [9140] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                                                       at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:480)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:466)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:236)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
05-02 15:02:41.860 12952-12952/com.sandro.openalprsample E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

If need any more information I can update.

Comment: Which target version does your app have?

Comment: Currently 23 is target

Comment: And which part specifically does not work?

Comment: It looks like the request permission from API23, I believe you need to check the build API to ask permission or not (before 23, the manifest is used, since 23 you need to ask on runtime)

Comment: Basically idea is, I try to send information to database, with API23 by using this permissions is sending information successful, but back on API 21 I have this error which starts like this: E/Volley: [8008] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception

Comment: @J.FOG from which line this exception occurs ? Edit your request with a stacktrace

Comment: I'm removing my answer since this as nothing to do with your problem. This as nothing to do with the code you provide. The exception came from the encoding of your parameter. As it is writen, you work with a null instance of String. Without more info, I can't really find where it come from.

Comment: @AxelH I red few post about similar problem. the main this IF this is with a null instance of String, WHY then of API 23 everything working perfectly?

Comment: The only thing I can thing of is you forgot to add a permission in the manifest. But I can't help you i I don't know what the code is doing when the exception occurs.

Comment: I can show full code of this class, if this will help?

Comment: I guess ... I never use the Volley package but it look like it can't find the parameters, are you sure that the connection was made in API23 ? Because the requestPermission is asynchronous, if the popup request is shown, you already return false so your method is not call. Just saying ;)